Problem with Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
I have Ubuntu 22-04 and a new machine with the above audio device. I cannot receive any audio output.
I have put this down to the lack of a driver in 22-04 to connect to the audio device. Am I correct?
Will the new version of Ubuntu, namely 24-04, rectify this problem by providing the necessary driver support?
